# Load X509Certificates from selected folder

Tags: c#, x509, certificate-store

Load X509 Certificates from Folder

I'm using c#, and i need to load X509 certificates from a folder.I need to load files from folder to show in a table inside my encryption program.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, storeLocation: StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("E-mail", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("valid from", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Expiry Date", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("ThumbPrint", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc5);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
        {
            string email1 = mCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
            string stringAfterChar = email1.Substring(email1.IndexOf("-") + 1);
            string name = mCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
            string[] splitString = name.Split('-');

            string namewithoutemail = splitString[0].Trim();

            dt.Rows.Add(namewithoutemail , stringAfterChar,  mCert.NotBefore, mCert.GetExpirationDateString() , mCert.Thumbprint);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

This is my code and actually I can load Certificates from CertificateStore but I want to load certificates from folder.Other thing i can do its create a special certificate store to my program but i think it's impossible.
Thanks for any help

Comment: A bit strange but maybe [StoreName.AddressBook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=netframework-4.7.2) matches your requirement. It says something about "other users certificates"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the reference for [X509Certificate2.Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Import_System_String_). This allows you load a certificate from the filesystem (among other methods). In this case, you would simply loop through the certificate files in your folder rather than opening the CertificateStore.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(yourFolder, "*.cer"))
        {
            var mCert = X509Certificate2.Import(file);

            string email1 = mCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
            string stringAfterChar = email1.Substring(email1.IndexOf("-") + 1);
            string name = mCert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false);
            string[] splitString = name.Split('-');

            string namewithoutemail = splitString[0].Trim();

            dt.Rows.Add(namewithoutemail , stringAfterChar,  mCert.NotBefore, mCert.GetExpirationDateString() , mCert.Thumbprint);
        }
```

Comment: As an alternative there is a X509Certificate2 ctor that admits the filename of the cert file